# resize modal according to iframe content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I have a modal that I want to resize according to the iframe content size.

I can make the modal big , but the content of iframe is still coming with scroll bars.

Here is the link to github page. click on the modal "One Minute Story" link on the top left.

[page](http://rahulraina7.github.io/graph_dashboard/)

I want the modal to be exactly centered and the iframe content which is an svg chart to come perfectly inside it without scrolls.

```
<div id="story-modal" class="modal hide fade" >
  <div class="modal-header">
        <a href="#" class="close">&times;</a>
        <h3>1 Minute Story!</h3>
      </div>

    <div id="storyChart" >

    </div>
<script type="text/javascript">$("#storyChart").append($("<iframe />").attr("src", "/frame.html"));
</script>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put following code

```
#story-modal {
height: 500px;
width: 590px;
}
#storyChart {
height: auto;
width: 100%;
position: relative;
overflow-y: hidden;
overflow-x: hidden;
}
Put this code in iframe
<iframe src="/frame.html" width="200" height="200" style="
    width: 100%;
    height: 520px;"></iframe>
```

for h1 some width is written because of which horizontal scroll is coming

```
.container h1{
width: 100%;
position: relative;
/* left: -100px; */
letter-spacing: -1px;
line-height: 60px;
font-size: 60px;
font-weight: 100;
margin: 0px 0 50px 0;
text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff;
}
```

It's working properly with this changes